# Customized implementation in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

For my project I made changes and added two functions in `hog.cpp` under `opencv/modules/gpu/src`. Following are the two functions that I added to get the functionality that I want.

- getDescriptorsMultiScale
- getDescriptorsBlock

I also have to add the definition of these two functions under `opencv/modules/gpu/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp`

At the moment I am just replacing these files under specified folders mentioned above. My supervisor asked me to separate the original OpenCV implementation and my own version and add symbolic link to my implementation. At the moment I have no clue how I can do that. Can someone please let me know how I can do that please.

**EDIT** 
I rename the original opencv file with hog_original.cpp and created another directory structure similar to opencv and created the file hog.cpp(my implementation) and when I tried to link the file. I got the following error. `ln: failed to create symbolic link file exist`

Comment: Your question could have been: how do I make a symbolic link? you would probably have found a lot of results at google ;)

Comment: Make sure you do it like `ln -s /your/file.cpp /opencv/folder/file.cpp`, and use an absolute path for your file. Anyway, you can also copy-paste it.

Comment: I did and still the same error @alesegdia

Comment: you can see the commaind `ln -s /home/shah/Projects/TUE_Multiclass_Detector/src/opencv/modules/gpu/src/hog.cpp /home/shah/Downloads/opencv-2.4.9/modules/gpu/src/hog_original.cpp`

Comment: `ln -s /home/shah/Projects/TUE_Multiclass_Detector/src/opencv/modules/gpu/src/hog.cpp /home/shah/Downloads/opencv-2.4.9/modules/gpu/src/hog.cpp`

Comment: still the same issue. I am gonna die @alesegdia

Comment: make sure `/home/shah/Downloads/opencv-2.4.9/modules/gpu/src/hog.cpp` was removed (you copied it to `hog_original.cpp`, so no problem with that)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89702/discussion-between-alesegdia-and-shah).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, but I think it's just to place OpenCV files elsewhere and

```
ln -s /path/to/your/files.[hc]pp /path/to/opencv/folder/files.[hc]pp
```

then compile with your version of those files instead of OpenCV ones.

In other words, copy-paste your files into OpenCV source folder and compile to test your implementation, but keep original OpenCV files safe.

[More info on symbolic links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link)

Comment: I rename the original opencv file with hog_original.cpp and created another directory structure similar to opencv and created the file hog.cpp(my implementation) and when I tried to link the file. I got the following error. `ln: failed to create symbolic link file exist` @alegesdia